# one Arduino with RS485 and Ethernet shields: does this work?

Tags: ethernet, rs485

I'm planning to wire a few Arduinos together via RS485, and have one of them act as a hub that collects information from the others and presents it via http on an Ethernet connection.

For instance an Aduino MKR with [ETH shield](https://store.arduino.cc/mkr-eth-shield) and [485 shield](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mkr-485-shield). Can I expect these to work together? My worry is having 2 shields that potentially need lots of bandwidth, timing issues etc.

Comment: no problem for MKR

Answer (score 1):

Should be no problem.

The ETH shield uses SPI to communicate with a W5500 chip. That chip does most of the network processing for you.

The 485 shield just connects to the UART TX and RX pins. It's just serial communications with a couple of control pins from there on out.

Neither use any pins that the other one uses.